NoSuchMethodException: BluetoothAdapter on release builds
My application is crashing out with the error Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: f4.b.<init> [class android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter] when I run it in release mode. The app works fine if run in debug mode, or even release mode when installed via Android Studio. The problem is exclusively when running a release build which has been installed via our MDM solution. The stack trace doesn't appear to me to be particularly helpful:
   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.MYAPP, PID: 22867
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.MYAPP/com.MYAPP.ui.BluetoothConnectionsActivity}: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: f4.b.<init> [class android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter]
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3271)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3410)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2017)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7397)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: f4.b.<init> [class android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter]
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2332)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1728)
    at f4.c.a(Unknown Source:8)
    at androidx.lifecycle.v0.d(Unknown Source:0)
    at h.r2.j(Unknown Source:70)
    at h.r2.i(Unknown Source:12)
    at com.MYAPP.ui.BluetoothConnectionsActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source:55)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7882)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7871)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1316)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3246)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3410) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2017) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7397) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935) 

I have tried setting minifyEnabled false and shrinkResources false but this doesn't seem to make any difference

It does still look a lot like an obfuscation issue given the clearly obfuscated name of the method that isn't resolved.
f4.b.<init>

You type you've tried minifyEnabled false and shrinkResources false.
Instead try updating your obfuscation rules with the options below. By default these are found at proguard-rules.pro, for other options check https://developer.android.com/build/shrink-code:
-dontshrink
-dontobfuscate
-dontoptimize

If that resolves the problem you can then fine tune to exclude the actual code causing this issue from obfuscation. You can check in your mapping output what these symbols map to.
If that doesn't work update this post with a simplified project to reproduce the problem and/or mapping files.

You were correct, the problem was indeed an obfuscation issue. I followed your advice and was then able to track down the offending classes/methods
